# How to configure ISC DHCPD for HP thin client ezUpdate (DHCP tag 137)?

Tags: dhcp, hp, thin-client

We have a series of HP Thin Clients deployed which support their ezUpdate protocol.  On boot, it checks in with the DHCP server and looks for tag 137 to get the FTP URL to connect to to check for updates.  Our DHCP server is ISC DHCPD and I cannot determine how to configure the options to give out this tag/code with the rest of the DHCP lease information.  This is my first foray into ISC DHCPD so please be gentle.  Any guidance is appreciated.

Note: The content of the tag would be a string with a URL in the format `ftp://user:pass@ftp.example.com`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a [little guide](http://www.linuxmanpages.com/man5/dhcp-options.5.php#lbAJ) since I'm not sure if it's text or an IP addy alone.

It's probably something like:

```
option hpezupd code 137 = text;
option hpezupd "ftp://user:pass@ftp.example.com";
```

Note: You have to define the option in the general configuration; the option assignment can be in a subnet definition or similar.

Comment: Thanks, I believe that will do it.  I modified the answer slightly to reflect the specific device I'm using (HP t5325) in case someone else with an HP thin client happens to wander by later.